# Partial File Name as Shell Script Input

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script that takes a partial file name as its input and then does operations on the files with the matching names. For example, I have three files `sample1.txt,sample2.txt and sample3.txt` and this is my script

```
#!bin/bash

VALUE=$1
VALUE2=$2
FILE_NAME=$3

echo $FILE_NAME
```

And I run it with this command

```
sh myscript.sh arg1 arg2 sample*
```

But I get this as the output

```
sample3.txt (sample2.txt)
```

But what I want is

```
sample1.txt
sample2.txt
sample3.txt
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You are passing an argument list from the sender (i.e. `sample*` could be any number of files). So use an array (list) at the receiver to get all the arguments (`"$@"`) and not just the first

Comment: do `FILE_NAME=("$@")` and print the whole array i.e. `printf '%s\n' "${FILE_NAME[@]}"`

Comment: @InianWhat if I have other arguments too? I have edited the question

Comment: Use the `shift` command to shift the positional arguments. In your case to skip two arguments do `shift 2; FILE_NAME=("$@")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample*
```

get's expanded into (if the files exists, no more files with that name, etc):

```
sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt
```

So when you write:

```
sh myscript.sh arg1 arg2 sample*
```

What you really write, what your script sees is:

```
sh myscript.sh arg1 arg2 sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt
```

Your script get's 5 arguments, not 3

Then you can:

```
#!bin/bash

VALUE=$1
VALUE2=$2

# shift the arguments to jump over the first two 
shift 2

# print all the rest of arguments
echo "$@"

# ex. read the arguments into an array
FILE_NAME=("$@")
echo "${FILE_NAME[@]}"
```

Live example at [jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/1dLP).